# Backing up bind mounted folders

Tags: mount, backup, lvm, deja-dup, bind

My layout is as follows.

LVM Setup: /dev/VG/Documents, /dev/VG/Music, /dev/VG/Pictures, /dev/VG/Music, /dev/VG/Documents, etc....

Each of the LVMs is bind mounted to the corresponding folder name in /home/foo. For example, /home/foo/Documents bind mounted to /media/Documents (mount point of /dev/VG/Documents), etc.

If I set up deja-dup to just back up my home folder, am I guaranteed that everything from my LVMs will be backed up properly? So let's say I take away my LVMs for some reason and choose to restore an earlier backup. My home folder will contain everything from the LVMs? All my docs, music, vids etc. My intuition tells me everything will be fine but it doesn't hurt to ask the the experts ;). Hope I have made myself clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  The bind mount is immaterial, and as long as your backup tool is not configured to only backup the one filesystem and not descend into any mount points ( like the `--one-file-system` option to `tar` ) then the subdirectories in those mount points will be backed up.